# Library to print all public fields of nested Java objects?

Tags: java, reflection, introspection

I need to print all public fields of nested Java objects. These objects only contain data, no methods. On any level of object tree (except leaf nodes) fields may be Maps, Lists, Sets and arrays. Leaf nodes are primitive types.
Nested field should be printed as a string of the following format:

```
<fieldName1>.<fieldName2>. ... <fieldNameN>==<value>
```

where:

```
<fieldName1> -- root (top level) field name
<fieldNameN> -- N-level field name
<value> -- N-level field value.
```

Any library out there to solve this task?

Answer (score 4):

The following example is far from being complete - it drafts a solution and shows some pitfalls:

```
public class Main {
    private static Set<Object> visited = new HashSet<Object>();
    public String s = "abc";
    public int i = 10;
    public Main INSTANCE = this;

public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception
{
   printFields(new Main(), "");
}

    private static void printFields(Object obj, String pre) throws Exception{
      Field[] fields = obj.getClass().getFields();
      for (Field field:fields) {
         String value = "";
         String type = field.getType().toString();

         // handle primitve values
         if (type.equals("int")) {
           value += field.getInt(obj);
         } 

         // handle special types, you may add Wrapper classes
          else if (type.equals("class java.lang.String")) {
           value = field.get(obj).toString();  
         } 

         // handle all object that you want to inspect
          else {
           if (visited.contains(field.get(obj))) {
             // necessary to prevent stack overflow
             value = "CYCLE DETECTED";
           } else {
             // recursing deeper
             visited.add(field.get(obj));
             pre += field.getName() + ".";
             printFields(field.get(obj), pre);
           }
         }     

         System.out.printf("%s%s = %s%n", pre, field.getName(), value);
      }
    }
}
```

- We find all we need in the reflection API
- We need recursion to walk down the object tree
- We need some special handling for primitives
- We want some special handling for immutable types (e.g. we don't want to recurse into a `String` object
- We need to take care if we visit an object twice.

*Note - the code is pretty ugly, hope, it's enough to give you an idea*

Comment: Yet, my sub-question remains: I need explicitly distinguish Map and Iterable to iterate these collections - another special case. How to find out that class implements specific interface, for example Map or Iterable?

Comment: I skipped that because: looking into collections doesn't fit with your format requirement. You *could* cheat with `get(0)` and `get(1)` for lists but your lost with sets (we can't get a single value from a set)

Comment: But anyway, once you've made up your mind on how to format the output *with* collections, you can insert "handlers" for collection type into the if/else chain. Like, if you see an array or list, then get all objects from the array/collection and inspect them one by one with the same `printFields` method.

Comment: Printing Map members can be done like that: `<fieldMapName>.<fieldKeyName>.<fieldOtherName>...` and for lists and arrays: `<fieldListName>.<fieldListElementName>.<fieldOtherName>...` where <fieldKeyName> and <fieldListElementName> are "pseudo-fields"

Answer (score 1):

No library necessary. This is called Reflection in java. Have a look at the [Class documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) using this you can do:

```
for(Field field : YourClass.class.getFields()){
    //Print field info
}
```

Edit:
You can get the class of a `Field` by doing `getDeclaringClass()`. This class can be checked to see if it is a primitive by doing `isPrimitive()`. If it is you can print the value. If not you can recurse and print the fields for this field.

Comment: Thanks, yes this a good way to find class fields. Yet I also need to find a leaf field value. So the question is - you have an object, a field name of an object nested at level N - how to find this deeply nested field value?

Comment: Also what if nested field is a Map, array or Iterable? Then you need to iterate down to all objects these collections contain. So as you see, to solve this task much more needs to be done ...

Comment: @dokondr I've added more information on this, all of which was available from the documentation I'd linked to.

Comment: @jim I see, thanks. Yet I need explicitly distinguish Map and Iterable to iterate these collections - another special case. How to find out that class implements specific interface, for example Map or Iterable?